# How to use simplify()

Tags: postgis, geoserver, vector, simplify

i have my Vector Data saved in a PostgreSQL PostGIS enabled Database.
The Data im displaying is very detailed, i want to simplify it through the simplify() method of Postgis.

I duplicated one of my tables (for test purposes to not mess up the real thing) and then used the simplify func"select ... simplify(...)..."

I got a result and inserted into the geom part of my new table.
After i created a new layer with this table as spatial information, whenever i click on Layer preview, im not greeted with a map, but with a download prompt for an xml which tells me i have an error.

Am i using the function wrong ?? or is my approach inside of geoserver wrong ??

Could i possibly save my current data as a shapefile, then simplify this and then let it be processed with pg2sql or something like that ??

Whenever i add the Layer to my Geoserver and press compute Bounding Boxes, geoserver comes up with 0, -1, 0, 1 .

Sorry if i have alot of questions but im really really stuck.

Answer (score 5):

The problem probably is that GeoServer needs to find your new table in "geometry_columns"

You can use the function [Populate_Geometry_Columns](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/Populate_Geometry_Columns.html) to put all the data about your table in the right place.

About simplifying, Paul Ramsey also have a great approach in his [blog](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2010/11/removing-complexities.html)

HTH
Nicklas